# Chaning the behavior of {{layout handle="" order=$order}}

Tags: layout

**Background information:**

In `app/locale/country_code/email/sales/order_new.html` you can edit the template which is used as an order confirmation.

Inside the order_new.html I have this code:

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

**What I need to do:**
I need to edit the behavior of that specific layout. Where can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In this case,you need to check `sales_email_order_items` handler  mapped template & blocks types.

See at sales.xml at app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTemplate/layout/

```
  <sales_email_order_items>
        <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
                <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
                <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
                <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                    <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
                </block>
            </block>
        </block>
        <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
    </sales_email_order_items>
```

you can the change here.

Comment: this code should be placed in local.xml ??

Comment: i will suggested  to you copy sales app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/ to app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTemplate/layout/